# R - ggplot passing color by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

**file.csv**

```
group   metric
"1"       1.1
"0"       2.2
"0"       3.3
"1"       4.4
```

I'm reading the above `file.csv` as below in to a data frame

```
df <- read.csv("file.csv", header=T)
# store col names for using later
group_name <- colnames(df)[1]
metric_name <- colnames(df)[2]
```

While creating a box plot, I need to pass the color through variable `group_name`

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df[,group_name], y=df[,metric_name], color=group_name ) ) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="darkred", outlier.shape = NA, fill = fill, color=line, alpha = 0.5) +
  theme(legend.position = c(1, 1), legend.justification = c(1, 1))
p
```

The issue is that the legend in the plot shows as `group_name` instead of the value of the variable `group_name` - what is needed to done so that color takes the value of the variable `group_name` ?

The reason for using `x=df[,group_name]` in `aes` is so as to make it generally applicable for any csv files whole column name may not be known.

Comment: Why are you subsetting your dataframe inside the `ggplot` call? Do `aes(x = group, y = metric, color = group)` instead

Comment: I just wonder if you have any reasons why you store column names as you do.

Comment: The "ggplot2" way of going about this would be to include a third column in your original data.frame and use syntax @yeedle suggested.

Comment: @jazzurro - the reason I do call the ggplot in this way is to generalize the code. If I use the column names, then it would need changes to work with datasets coming with different names. If I use the subsetting the way in the question, the column names doesn't matter.

Comment: @yeedle - see comment above.

Comment: @yeedle - think about it as writing a function that takes a data frame as input and output the plot. The function doesn't know the column names till the df is called. So there something like  `customBoxPlot <- function(df) { }`

Comment: Well, one way to do that the ggplot way would be to use regular evaluation. That is, pass the column names to the function as strings, and use `aes_string` or `aes_q` instead of `aes` as outlined [in the docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/aes_string.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is just how the `ggplot` paradigm works. Normally the grouping variable is a factor or character vector describing an attribute rather than a number. Let's take some random data similar to your .csv:

```
group <- c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
metric <- rnorm(10, 1)
df <- data.frame(group, metric)
```

In your case you could use `dplyr::mutate` to add a new column as suggested in the comments. You can call the new column and variables whatever you like.

```
library(dplyr)
df.gp <- df %>% mutate(Group.new = paste("Group", group))

# df.gp
#    group     metric  Group.new
# 1      1  1.3100608    Group 1
# 2      0  2.7120827    Group 0
# 3      1 -0.2310713    Group 1
# etc
```

Now plot the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.gp, aes(x=Group.new, y=metric, fill=Group.new)) + geom_boxplot() +
theme(legend.position = c(1, 1), legend.justification = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: this is fine. but the question is why `color=group_name` is not giving the desired results ? what is the workaround for this ? I cannot refer colnames for x & y

Comment: I don't know. `ggplot2` is complex under the hood, and you don't need to do this anyway. If you want to use `ggplot2`, you'll have to get used to its grammar.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems from the comments, [user3206440](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3206440/user3206440)'s intention is to pass the column names to a function. The ggplot way to do it, as I mentioned in the comments, is as follows:

```r
customBoxPlot <- function(df, group_var, metric_var) { 

  ggplot(df, aes_string(x=group_var, y=metric_var, color=group_var)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="darkred", outlier.shape = NA, alpha = 0.5) +
    theme(legend.position = c(1, 1), legend.justification = c(1, 1))

}

customBoxPlot(df, names(df)[1], names(df)[2])
# or
customBoxPlot(df, "group", "metric")
```

This is how the output will look using your data:

[image: output]